# Executing Javascript in R?

Tags: javascript, html, css, r

Recently, I learned about the "highcharter" library in R (e.g. https://jkunst.com/highcharter/). There appears to be many interesting visualizations that are possible with this library - but there do not seem to be as many options as in the original "highchart" javascript libary (e.g. https://www.highcharts.com/).

I started looking at different visualization options that are available within the original "highchart" library and came across the following visualization : https://www.highcharts.com/demo/packed-bubble-split

I see here that there is an option to look at the source code that is used for these visualizations:

[image]

Lately, I have been learning how to execute HTML and Javascript code within R (e.g. R markdown). I had the following question:

**Is it possible for me to take the code that is provided here and somehow render this code in R, and thereby producing these exact same visualizations in R?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes this is possible in RMarkdown (and I assume Quarto, though I haven't made the change yet;-).

The key is to

1. load JS libraries into the body of the HTML document; this can be easily done using `htmltools` inside an R code chunk. You can see the relevant JS libraries in the HTML part, as given [in the JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/packed-bubble-split).

   ````r
   ```{r, echo = FALSE}
   htmltools::tagList(
     htmltools::tags$script(src = "https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"),
     htmltools::tags$script(src = "https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"),
     htmltools::tags$script(src = "https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"),
     htmltools::tags$script(src = "https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js")
   )
   ```
   ````
2. Place a `<div>` element directly inside the RMarkdown document

   ```html
   <div id="container"></div>
   ```
3. Finally, include the JS code inside a JS code chunk, the output of which we suppress with `echo = FALSE`

   ````r
   ```{js, echo = FALSE}
   // JS code goes in here
   ```
   ````

   The JS code is the full "Javascript + No-library (pure JS)" code that contains the data and constructs the packed bubble chart, as given [in the JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/packed-bubble-split).

I have put together a [reproducible Gist](https://gist.github.com/mevers/eb4b8eeb000752fd87f81aaf6647e978) with a full sample Rmd document, including the JS code from https://www.highcharts.com/demo/packed-bubble-split.

Knitting the Rmd document then gives the following (interactive but static screenshot here) plot

[image]